# Horizontal Scrollbar Removed from site

Tags: css, wordpress

A have a horizontal scroll appearing on my site and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

http://global-markets-recruitment.com/test/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe some code errors: [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  global-markets-recruitment.com test  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//global-markets-recruitment.com/test/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. And you have several div widths set to 1200px.

Comment: the horizontal scrollbar is still there even if I reduce it to 940px

Comment: Look at the code validation report and fix your unclosed div and your duplicate div.

Answer (score 0):

style.css line 57. You made your header 1200px wide. That's big.

```
#header {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Actually you have other very wide elements too.

```
#contentHolder
{
    width: 1200px;
}

#contentShadow
{
    width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: the horizontal scrollbar is still there even if I reduce it to 940px

Comment: @user1096057 - you could just add `overflow: hidden` to your body tag.

Comment: that seems to of shifted the whole website to the left and has cut off part of the site

Comment: but it has removed the horizontal scrollbar